# Get sum of values in object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that consists of *n* array items, each containing a `name` and `price` key. I'm attempting to retrieve, and sum the values of `price` in each of the entries. How do I access these values in the first place, and then sum them together?

```
const items = [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "price": 280000000000,
    },
    {
        "symbol": "B",
        "price": 92000000000,
    },
    {
        "symbol": "C",
        "floorPrice": 96000000000,
    }
]
```

Comment: Use `total += items[i].price` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "price": 280000000000,
    },
    {
        "symbol": "B",
        "price": 92000000000,
    },
    {
        "symbol": "C",
        "floorPrice": 96000000000,
    }
]
var price = 0;
items.map((item) =>  {
   if(item.hasOwnProperty("price")){price+=item.price}
   else if(item.hasOwnProperty("floorPrice")){price+=item.floorPrice}
   //... if more property 
})
console.log(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Array.reduce method available in JavaScript.
Since you're objects have different keys for "price" you'd want to check which keys are present to add them to the total sum.

Reduce takes in an accumulator (running total) and current value(current spot in array. It loops through the desired values and adds them to the running total.

```
const sum = items.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
  if(curr.price){
    return acc + curr.price
  } else {
    return acc + curr.floorPrice
  }
 
 }, 0);

console.log(sum);
```